How do I optimise a piece-wise continuous, multiple argument, Python function containing conditional statements to operate on NumPy arrays?
I'm relatively new to Python programming and NumPy, but I have an engineering background and have used VBA extensively.  I am currently using Python to analyse gas dynamic problems which involve mathematically complex and sometimes discontinuous functions (shock waves and transitional flows).  I'd like some help with piecewise-continuous function programming.
This is a simplified version of one aspect of what I'm doing.  I have a piecewise-continuous function in two variables:
f(Re, r) = fL(Re, r),  Re<2000 for all r
f(Re, r) = fT(Re, r),  Re>= 2000 for all r
I've tested various options to calculate f, including loops, vectorised scalar function, numpy.where(), numpy.select(), numpy.piecewise() and various forms of boolean indexing.  numpy.piecewise() seems to offer the most elegant solution, but I can't see how to work with two arguments.  Hopefully the code below will make it clear; any help or comments much appreciated.
Is there a way to implement numpy.piecewise() function with two arguments in an element-wise fashion?
Is my solution with boolean indexing below a sensible one, noting that the arrays could get quite big?
import numpy as np

def fL(Re, r):
    return 16.0/Re

def fT(Re,r):
    return ((-1.8*np.log10((r/3.7)**1.11 + 6.9/Re))**-2.0)/4.0

Re = np.logspace(3., 7., 5)

# This works fine for a scalar value of r:
r = 0.0001
def f0(Re, r):
    return np.piecewise(Re, [Re<2000.0, Re>=2000.0], [fL, fT], r)
print('\n       Re: ', Re)
print('        r: ', r)
print('f0(Re, r): ', f0(Re, r))

# This works element-wise for arrays of Re and r (which is what I want):
r = np.full_like(Re, 0.0001)
def f1(Re, r):
    fct = np.zeros(len(Re))
    fct[Re < 2000.0] = fL(Re[Re < 2000.0], r[Re < 2000.0])
    fct[Re >= 2000.0] = f0(Re[Re >= 2000.0], r[Re >= 2000.0])
    return fct
print('\n       Re: ', Re)
print('        r: ', r)
print('f1(Re, r): ', f1(Re, r))

# but this does not work element-wise:
print('\n      Re: ', Re)
print('       r: ', r)
print('f(Re, r): ', f0(Re, r))


(1) I assume that should be fT (the turbulent friction factor) in f1. (2) The masking you do in f1 is fine, but it won't work for scalar Re and r (which you might be okay with, depending on your application). You can speed it up a bit by creating a mask variable so you're not computing the mask 6 times (which is what your current code does). That will help for larger arrays. (I can show that in an answer if you need.)

Your laminar flow friction factor is a very cheap function to evaluate. It might be quicker to initialise your entire array to that, then overwrite with the turbulent one where the Reynolds number is big enough. BTW, are you sure that your formulation is continuous at the transition Reynolds number? Also, to the power of -2.0 might be more efficiently evaluated as 1/(value*value)

Thanks both; yes, I do mean fT in f1. Thanks for highlighting a mask variable, that makes sense. I'll do an experiment with initialising the array, but it is not static and might switch between turbulent and laminar at any point in space or time. I avoided laminar-turbulent transition for simplicity - final application will need three piecewise functions. I'm keen to get clear understanding of the coding principals before implementing the physics.  The turbulent function will be more complex in practice, but I'll look for any integer powers that can be replaced by products.  Thanks again!

"but I'll look for any integer powers that can be replaced by products" the point was that 1/np.ndarray**2 might be faster than np.ndarray**-2, particularly for large arrays.

In general, I would suggest working with the numpy functions that most succinctly describe what you'd like to do. In this case, I'd opt for
out = np.where(
    Re < 2000.0,
    fL(Re, r),
    fT(Re, r)
)

If you have more conditions, I'd go for np.select.
In either case, I'd accept that we're computing fL and fT at least partially on a domain where they aren't defined, if it is "fast enough".
np.piecewise internally does exactly what you are already doing with your boolean indexing solution, just a bit more generalized. Your solution is IMO very sensible, exactly how I'd approach it.
The sad issue is that np.piecewise cleanly passes the full r through to fL and fT, but only the subset of Re values where the conditions hold.
I can't think of any way to make np.piecewise work for your problem, so your f1 is your best bet in that case.
That being said, if performance is your bottle-neck, you might be served even better by some sort of (just-in-time) compiled function via e.g. numba

Thanks.  I've done some experiments with np.where and np.select, but I run into the potential for some functions to throw an exception if they're outside their valid range, hence I looked at np.piecewise.  It's reassuring to know my f1 is not wide of the mark; with the efficiencies highlighted in comments above I think it should work. I'm not familiar with numba so I'll spend an hour on Google and give it some thought.

@MurrayAnderson numba will only be useful if you plan on calling this function many times. Otherwise, the overheard of compilation will overshadow the speed improvement.

I mentioned in a comment that you can use a single mask. To clarify, what I mean about using a single mask is that in the function you are computing 6 masks, but you can do it once and use it for the rest of the function.
def f1(Re, r):
    fct = np.zeros_like(Re)
    mask = Re < 2000.0
    fct[mask] = fL(Re[mask], r[mask])
    fct[~mask] = fT(Re[~mask], r[~mask])
    return fct

If you don't know, ~mask means boolean NOT on the mask array, so it selects the opposite of mask.
I'm not sure how large Re will be, but this will be faster if Re is large.
